# Form values are not inserting into my database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

My form values are printing on this page but they are not inserting into my 
   database. I don't know what is wrong? If all the values are printing
   that means values are reaching on this particular page but not going into 
   database.Even the columns in the database are sorted, but it still doesn't 
   work.

```
 <?php
 include("connection.php");
 if(isset($_POST['continue']))
   {
echo $eta_type = $_POST['eta_type'];
echo     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
echo      $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
echo     $title1=$_POST['title1'];
echo    $dob=$_POST['dob'];
echo    $gender=$_POST['gender'];                         
echo   $nationality=$_POST['nationality'];         
echo    $cob=$_POST['cob'];         
echo   $passportnumber=$_POST['passportnumber'];
echo  $pid=$_POST['pid'];                            
echo  $ped=$_POST['ped'];   
echo $residence=$_POST['residence']; 
echo  $possesseta=$_POST['possesseta'];
echo $multipleentry=$_POST['multipleentry'];
echo   $arrivaldate=$_POST['arrivaldate'];
echo   $purpose=$_POST['purpose'];
echo   $final_dest=$_POST['final_dest'];
echo   $stay_days=$_POST['stay_days'];
echo $add1=$_POST['add1'];
echo   $add2=$_POST['add2'];
echo    $city=$_POST['city'];
echo    $state=$_POST['state'];
echo   $pscode=$_POST['pscode'];
echo    $country=$_POST['country'];
echo   $addlanka=$_POST['addlanka'];
echo $email=$_POST['email'];
echo   $alternate_email=$_POST['alternate_email'];
echo   $phone=$_POST['phone'];
echo $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
echo  $fax=$_POST['fax'];
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pid));
$date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ped));
$date4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrivaldate));
$address=$add1.$add2;
$sql= "INSERT INTO 
user(applicationtype,
surname,givenname,
title,dob,gender,nationality,
cob,passportnumber,pid,ped,
residenceinsrilanka,processeta,
multipleentryofsrilanka,intentedarrivaldate,
purposeofvisit,finaldestination,staydays,address,
city,state,postalcode,country,addinsrilanka,email,
alternateemail,telephonenos,mobilenos,faxnos) 
VALUES('$eta_type','$lastname','$firstname','$title1',
'$date1','$gender','$nationality','$cob',
'$passportnumber','$date2','$date3','$residence',
'$possesseta','$multipleentry','$date4','$purpose',
'$final_dest','$stay_days','$address','$city',
'$state','$pscode','$country','$addlanka','$email',
'$alternate_email','$phone','$mobile','$fax')";
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 if($query)
    {
      header("Location: continue-to-pay.php?pno=$passportnumber");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h4 style='color:red'>Failed.</h4>";
    }
   } 
   ?>
```

Comment: print `$sql` variable and paste this query in your sql query section and run. you will find actual reasons.

Comment: values are printing if I print $sql but not inserting into database. @RohitSuthar

Comment: run `$sql` query directly in your sql query section. if not insert, you will get an error message on your `phpmyadmin` page. it's may be database table issues not php scripts.

Comment: Please try what  is suggested by @RohitSuthar. Print `$sql` and copy paste that query in SQL console... you'll easily find the exact reason...!!

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly dangerous code...

Read some about query injection....

Any value passed this way can break your query.

You need to escape your values with `mysqi_escape_string()`

http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php